# NFSv4 with sec=krb5: Encryption type aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192 not permitted

Tags: kerberos, nfs4

The upgrade from Fedora 38 to 39 broke mounting NFSv4 shares from a Synology NAS using kerberos (`sec=krb5`). Using

```
mount -v -t nfs -o nfsvers=4,minorversion=1,sec=krb5 10.123.99.2:/volume1/video /mnt/
```

on the **Fedora 39** client, I get the following error:

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sat Feb 24 12:25:20 2024
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=4,sec=krb5,vers=4.1,addr=10.123.99.2,clientaddr=10.123.99.10'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 10.123.99.2:/volume1/video
```

Fortunately, the information on the Synology NAS (server) is a bit more helpful: I get the following error in `/var/log/messages`:

```
svcgssd[10330]: ERROR: GSS-API: error in handle_nullreq: gss_accept_sec_context(): GSS_S_FAILURE (Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information) - Encryption type aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192 not permitted
```

As another **Fedora 38** still works flawlessly, I suppose that the new **Fedora 39** system defaults to a new encryption type that the Synology NAS does not support. Thus, I tried `allow_weak_crypto = true`, `default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96` and/or `default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96` in `/etc/krb5.conf` with no effect on the issue and its error message on the server. (It broke logging in with my standard user name. I use a FreeIPA server for authorization and authentication so I guess this doesn't like the other encryption.)

On reddit, I got the hint to play with `update-crypto-policies`. This didn't work either.

Is there any way to set which encryption is used? Or do you think that there is another issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Synology has had numerous problems with Kerberos encryption types in the past two years.

Comment: `aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192` is encryption type 20. I don't believe Windows supports that either. You may want to change the `permitted_enctypes` value to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kerberos enctypes for each service are set on the KDC. When a client requests a service ticket, the KDC chooses the strongest type in common between what the client claims to support and what the KDC *thinks* the service will support (as the KDC does not communicate with the service).

For example, with MIT Kerberos you would specify a custom list of enctypes when generating the keytab via kadmin, or when setting the password for the service account (which generates keys on the KDC). On the other hand, Active Directory has the "Supports AES" checkboxes for this purpose.

I don't know how you'd do this with FreeIPA, but I assume it's part of the command that you've used to generate the `nfs/` keytab for Synology.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I think I did what you proposed but I now get: `ERROR: GSS-API: error in handle_nullreq: gss_accept_sec_context(): GSS_S_FAILURE (Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information) - No key table entry found for nfs/nas.vierwaende.home@VIERWAENDE.HOME`. I generated a new keytab with `ipa-getkeytab -p nfs/nas.vierwaende.home -k nfs_nas.keytab -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96,aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96` and uploaded it to the NAS. I can confirm that the NAS's keytab only included the encryption entries as requested, each with both, KVNO 2 and 3.

Comment: Did you upload it to the right location where rpc.svcgssd expects to find it? I don't know where it should go in your NAS, although standard Linux would expect both `host/` and `nfs/` in the same `/etc/krb5.keytab`, but I would assume Synology likely has it slightly different... Still, it looks like regular Linux nfs-utils, so if you have root on the NAS, I'd try restarting svcgssd with debug mode enabled, or try `strace` on its PID, etc. (the usual Linux investigation).

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind: Your clients need to get _new Kerberos tickets_ that would be correct for the new keytab, as currently they're probably trying to send their previously-obtained aes-sha384 tickets for the nfs/ service. Since you got a new keytab and regenerated the service keys, start with `kinit -R` to flush the cached tickets on the client, and maybe restart rpc.gssd on the client as well.

Comment: Thanks again! It's working now but I really don't know why now and not before. I deleted the tickets (`kdestroy`) and I rebooted both, client and NAS; it didn't work. Now it does and I didn't do anything else. Anyway, I will build my next NAS by self with a standard linux... ;) Thanks again for the help.